# how do i add a digits by getting previous information from text

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm building a simple game and I want to give a player 10 point each time he get's the answer, right before clicking next. But instead after clicking he gets the score and when he clicks again another score is added. Looks like  he is cheating. Pls how do I add just one for each button. Here is my code.

```
int d = Integer.parseInt(Counter.get text());
int e =10;   
int f=d+10;

counter.set text(f+"");
```

`counter` is the name of my textfeild that displays output

Answer (score 1):

Either you `disable the button` after click

OR

Get some information from `last clicked` button & when user clicks again, check the `last information` with the `current information`, if both are same, then user clicked again, so block it.

Comment: Wow thanks but can you give me an example? Am not a professional yet.

Comment: When you click on the button, then get some ID or anything unique related to that particular button, then store it in some variable like `lastClicked = SOMEID`, now when again the user clicks on that button, you will again get the same ID. Now check `if(lastClicked == currentClicked)`, if yes then user double clicked the button. So block. I am giving you the solution of how much I can understand your situation.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Please just do me a real example.thanks ur owesome